# Using TensorFlowEstimator's "partial_fit" within a loop? (Keeps creating new TensorFlow device each iteration)

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am currently putting together my first RNN + LSTM model in TensorFlow.

I would like to try to train the nework on some "live" sensor data but given the examples I have found on the web it is not clear to me how I can resolve an issue where my training updates are very slow.

I think what is happening is for each iteration in the loop, TensorFlow opens/creates a new TF device (in this case my two GPUs) then after processing on a single sample it closes them, then re-opens... This adds about 3 seconds to each training cycle regardless of batch size.

Here is some code that shows how I have the estimator configured and how I call it from within a loop:

```
from tensorflow.contrib import learn

regressor = learn.TensorFlowEstimator(model_fn=lstm_model(TIMESTEPS, RNN_LAYERS, DENSE_LAYERS),
                                      n_classes=0,
                                      verbose=0,
                                      batch_size=1,
                                      steps=1,
                                      optimizer='Adagrad',
                                      learning_rate=0.03,
                                      continue_training=True
                                      )
for x in range(10): #loop while sensor data is streaming in
    print(x)
    X, y = get_sensors_data() #get a single sample of sensor data
    regressor.partial_fit(
        X['train'][x].reshape((1,10,1)),
        y['train'][x].reshape((1,1)),
        steps=1
    )
    #predict_next_position()
```

As the above code executes I get some verbose output (even though verbose=0):

```
0
INFO:tensorflow:Create CheckpointSaverHook
INFO:tensorflow:Create CheckpointSaverHook
I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:925] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:951] Found device 0 with properties: 
name: GeForce GTX 1070
major: 6 minor: 1 memoryClockRate (GHz) 1.7845
pciBusID 0000:03:00.0
Total memory: 8.00GiB
Free memory: 7.10GiB
W tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_driver.cc:572] creating context when one is currently active; existing: 0x5c2f230
I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:925] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:951] Found device 1 with properties: 
name: GeForce GTX 1070
major: 6 minor: 1 memoryClockRate (GHz) 1.7845
pciBusID 0000:01:00.0
Total memory: 8.00GiB
Free memory: 7.02GiB
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:855] cannot enable peer access from device ordinal 0 to device ordinal 1
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:855] cannot enable peer access from device ordinal 1 to device ordinal 0
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:972] DMA: 0 1 
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:982] 0:   Y N 
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:982] 1:   N Y 
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1041] Creating TensorFlow device (/gpu:0) -> (device: 0, name: GeForce GTX 1070, pci bus id: 0000:03:00.0)
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1041] Creating TensorFlow device (/gpu:1) -> (device: 1, name: GeForce GTX 1070, pci bus id: 0000:01:00.0)
INFO:tensorflow:loss = 0.285131, step = 1
INFO:tensorflow:loss = 0.285131, step = 1
INFO:tensorflow:Saving checkpoints for 1 into /tmp/tmptouwbf48/model.ckpt.
INFO:tensorflow:Saving checkpoints for 1 into /tmp/tmptouwbf48/model.ckpt.
1
And Repeat...
```

I'm not positive if my approach is an efficient way for training this kind of configuration, but I'm quite new to this field. Any advice would be graciously welcomed!

Comment: Try to use the pipeline so that every step new data would be fetch by the pipeline.